# convert results from for-loop array to a new array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have the following code that gets Channel and AP Count values from XML test.xml.  I need to create a PHP Jpgraph based on these results.  Therefore, I will need to store for-loop results for **$channel** and **$apcount** into two separate arrays : x-axis[ ] and y-axis[ ]

```
<? 
$feed = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns", "urn:broadband-forum-org:ipdr:tr-232-1-0");

$number_of_entries = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.ResultNumberOfEntries']/ns:Value"); 
$number_of_entries = $number_of_entries[0];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_entries; $i++) {

$channel = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.{$i}.Channel']/ns:Value"); 
$channel = $channel[0]; 

$apcount = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.{$i}.APcount']/ns:Value");
$apcount = $apcount[0]; 

}
?>
```

here is the test.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ipdr:IPDRDoc xmlns:ipdr="http://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr"
xmlns="urn:broadband-forum-org:ipdr:tr-232-1-0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:broadband-forum-org:ipdr:tr-232-1-0 tr-232-1-0-0-serviceSpec.xsd http://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr http://www.ipdr.org/public/IPDRDoc3.5.1.xsd"
docId="74697373-6f74-7878-7878-746973736f74"
creationTime="2013-06-11T06:02:55.153Z"
IPDRRecorderInfo="IPDR Collector" version="3.5.1">
    <ipdr:IPDR xsi:type="BulkDataReport">
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.ResultNumberOfEntries</Name>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.1.Channel</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.1.APcount</Name>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.2.Channel</Name>
        <Value>6</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.2.APcount</Name>
        <Value>8</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.3.Channel</Name>
        <Value>11</Value>
    </BulkData>
    <BulkData>
        <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.X_181BEB_ChannelDiagnostics.Result.3.APcount</Name>
        <Value>6</Value>
    </BulkData>
    </ipdr:IPDR >
    <ipdr:IPDRDoc.End count="1" endTime="2013-06-11T06:02:55.207Z"></ipdr:IPDRDoc.End>
</ipdr:IPDRDoc>
```

The final result I am expecting are two arrays:

```
print_r($x-axis);  
Array ( 
   [0] => 1 
   [1] => 6 
   [2] => 11 
   ) 

print_r($y-axis);  
Array ( 
   [0] => 3 
   [1] => 8 
   [2] => 6 
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use code like this

before loop initialize two arrays

```
  $y-axis=array();
  $x-axis=array();
```

inside loop

```
  $x-axis[]=$channel[0];
  $y-axis[]=$apcount[0];
```

Comment: It is getting closer.  This is what I get now: Array ( 
 [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1 ) 
 [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 6 ) 
 [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 11 ) 
 )

Comment: This works fine in PHP 5.3 but for some reason it does not work in PHP 5.4 any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

@rakimo Your suggestion got me half the way.  I added the code below after the loop and it worked great.  Thanks!

```
foreach ($x-axis as $k => &$v) {
    $a = (array)$v;
    $v = $a[0];
    }
foreach ($y-axis as $s => &$t) {
    $b = (array)$t;
    $t = $b[0];
}
```